# Using built-in functions in custom functions

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I for a value on a page with google-sheets.

Currently, I am using  `=IMPORTHTML($A$1; "table" ; 2)`  but I would like to iterate with a custom function through the indexes.

How do I have to call the `IMPORTHTML` function in the custom function/ script-editor to run thru all indexes?

```
var current =IMPORTHTML(URL;  "table" ; i)
```

Results in the

> ReferenceError:  "IMPORTHTML"

.

Comment: Hey, I just posted an answer with two ways you can do this. Let me know if that works for you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

probably not the answer you expect but:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(
 IMPORTHTML(A1; "table" ; 2); 
 IMPORTHTML(A1; "table" ; 3)); 
 IMPORTHTML(A1; "table" ; 4));
 IMPORTHTML(A1; "table" ; 5))
```

etc...

or in an array:

```
={IMPORTHTML(A1; "table" ; 2);
  IMPORTHTML(A1; "table" ; 3);
  IMPORTHTML(A1; "table" ; 4);
  IMPORTHTML(A1; "table" ; 5))}
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but i want to search thru the result for a specific entry... but depending on the URL the index may change...

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, calling Sheets native functions from Google Apps Script is not supported.

However, you have the following options:

1. Use `setFormula()`. You can use the following code in order to set the formula to the sheet and extract the result from it back to the script.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("A20");

var formula = Utilities.formatString('=IMPORTHTML("%s", "%s", "%s")', URL, "table", i);
cell.setFormula(formula);
var value = cell.getValue();
```

2. Using the [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch).  You will have to implement code to extract the information you want (you can use [RegEx](https://scriptingwithshiva.blogspot.com/2018/04/google-apps-script-regular-expressions.html) or the [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)). It will take considerably more effort.